# Sum of Function Results

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that is generating a table. Ideally it should look like

```
+----+------+------+------+------+-------+
|    | Day1 | Day2 | Day3 | Day4 | Total |
+----+------+------+------+------+-------+
| C  | 5    | 5    | 5    | 5    | 20    |
| R  | $100 | $100 | $100 | $100 | $400  |
| CR | $500 | $500 | $500 | $500 | $2000 |
+----+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

Where `CR` is the `C * R` (this works), Total for C & R is `Sum(C)` (or R respectively, this works).

The issue is Total for CR. I should get $2000, but if I do `Sum(C) * Sum(R)` I get $8000. This is obviously because it's multiplying $400 * 20. Since CR is the results of a formula, I can't do `Sum(CR)`, it's not a field like C or R is.

What formula do I need to use to get the expected result?

**Edited to add**

C & R are each respectively formed by day as `Sum(C) or Sum(R)`. Each Day is a group in the report, with Total being outside the group.

[image]

C translates to Contract, R to Rate and CR to Contract Revenue. Where it has <> at top by Totals is the Days.

Comment: Can you also paste the screenshot of your Report design layout with Groups in it?

Comment: @CuriousKid Added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataset looks like it is a matrix in the the SSRS. So in that case use `SUM(C*R)`

```
=SUM(Fields!C.Value*Fields!R.Value)
```

Comment: Doesn't get me what I'm looking for, let me edit the question to show why (C & R are sums themselves).

Comment: I fixed the issue with my dataset coming in and this does work. Not for my initial dataset, but it is a valid answer so I'll give it that.